# How to replace the Alphabet from word in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question is to bring the below result using table 1 and 2 respectively.

TABLE 1

```
MQGRP   MQCOMPET
1   AV
2   UW|AV
```

Table 2

```
FullForm RecordKey
AVALON   AV
UWARON   UW
```

Result

```
MQGRP   MQCOMPET
1   AVALON
2   UWARON|AVALON
```

Comment: Is the separator between words usually | ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your DB is not normalized, so you cannot make a simple query to get what you need.

First you need to split the first table in rows like this:

```
1 AV
2 AV
2 UW
```

You need to create a table valued function that splits the `MQCOMPET` of the first table, and use it with `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` to get this first solution to your problem. [See this article to understand how they work](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/). See also [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows).

Then you need to join the rsult with table 2, to get something like this

```
1 AV AVALON
2 AV AVALON
2 UW UWARON
```

And finally you can use this technique to concatenate the values again:
[Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Answer (score 1):

Create a little Split Functions 1st

**Split Functions Definition**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split_Using_XML
 (
   @InputString NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @delimiter varchar(1) 
 )
 RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml AS XML;

    SET @xml  = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@InputString,@delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)

    INSERT INTO @t(val)
    SELECT C.value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS value
    FROM @xml.nodes('X') as X(C)
 RETURN;
END
```

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 TABLE (MQGRP INT,  MQCOMPET VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE1 VALUES 
(1   ,'AV'),
(2   ,'UW|AV')

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (FullForm VARCHAR(100), RecordKey VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES
('AVALON', 'AV'),
('UWARON', 'UW')
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT t.MQGRP
           ,t2.FullForm AS MQCOMPET
    FROM @TABLE1 t
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT val FROM dbo.Split_Using_XML(t.MQCOMPET, '|'))C(VAL)
    INNER JOIN @Table2 t2 
    ON C.val = t2.RecordKey
   ) 
SELECT C.MQGRP
      ,STUFF(( SELECT ' | ' + MQCOMPET
              FROM CTE
              WHERE MQGRP = C.MQGRP
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).
              value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS MQCOMPET
FROM CTE C
GROUP BY C.MQGRP
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════╦══════════════════╗
║ MQGRP ║     MQCOMPET     ║
╠═══════╬══════════════════╣
║     1 ║  AVALON          ║
║     2 ║  UWARON | AVALON ║
╚═══════╩══════════════════╝
```